# Groupby dataframe by columns and save to different directories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pandas-groupby

i have the following dataset:

```
X Y Z S A
_ _ _ _ _
0 1 2 1 1
8 5 3 1 2
5 6 7 2 1
9 8 9 2 2
6 7 7 1 3
```

i want to folder them accordingly their S and A columns like this

```
DATA\S1\A1
DATA\S1\A2
DATA\S2\A1
```

and I only want the corresponding XYZ values in my csv file

I have tried this piece of code. Creation of the folders work but I cannot save the corresponding csv file to proper folder. How should I fix the issue

**df is list that containing 3 different pandas-dataframes**

```
def write2path(df):
    path = getcwd()
    subjects = ["subject%d"%i for i in range(1,31)]
    activities = [str(i) for i in range(1,7)]
    try:
        path = path + "\\DATA"
        mkdir(path)
        
        for l in subjects:
            temp_path = path +"\\"+ l
            mkdir(temp_path)
            for k in activities:
                temp_path_child = temp_path +"\\" + k
                mkdir(temp_path_child)
                for j in range(len(df)):
                    ch='x'
                    
                    for i, x in df[j].loc[(['Subject0'] == int(l[7])) & (['Activity0'] == int(k))]: 
                        print(x)
                        val=chr(ord(ch)+j)
                        x.to_csv(temp_path_child+"\\"+f'sensor-{val}.csv', index=False)
```

```
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: False
```

[what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHcET.png)

Comment: in your actual file do unique groups of `S` and `A` span multiple rows - as in will `DATA\S1\A1` have more than a single row? your current df will be output as a single row, also can you explain logic for the file name?

Comment: sure. in My actual dataset i have 7300 rows that corresponding to multiple "Subjects" and "Activities" (6 activity label 30 subject label) . i want a DATA directory as parent of Each Subject directory. and each subject directories will have Activity(1,2,3,4,5,6) directories. in the activity directories, I will have the csv files that contain X Y Z Subject Activity as columns. DATA\subject1\Activity1\x-value.csv

Comment: i have added a picture of what i am trying to achieve for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use pathlib and use some tidy functions:

```
from pathlib import Path

def create_folder(path):
    if not path.is_dir():
        path.mkdir(parents=True)

def if_file_exists(filename,trg_folder,dataframe):
    if trg_folder.joinpath(file).is_file():
        # if file exists then write behavior here.
    else:
        dataframe.to_csv(trg_folder.joinpath(filename),index=False)
```

---

then list your fully qualfied start_dir in the variable below and groupby - write to your directory:

```
start_dir = r'your_start_dir' # like /tmp/files/data 

for paths, group in df.groupby(['S','A']):
    paths = list(map(str,paths)) # if ints.
    target_folder = Path(start_dir).joinpath('DATA','S'+paths[0],'A'+paths[1])
    create_folder(target_folder)
    file_name = f"S{paths[0]}-A{paths[1]}.csv"
    if_file_exists(file_name,target_folder,group)
```

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_start_dir\DATA\S1\A1\S1-A1.csv")

print(df)

   X  Y  Z  S  A
0  0  1  2  1  1
```

Comment: thank you for your help. What is the usage for def create_folder(path): ? we are not using it

Comment: @Nightingale my fault sorry - missed it when copying it in, see edit - its used to check if a folder exists or not, if not create it, Purpose of placing it in a function is to add any additional functionality if need be which makes your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: @Nightingale thanks - i'll have a think about a better way to generate the folder names instead of string interpolation (if you had say 3 or more variables it would get messy quick)

Comment: thank you, i have found a solution for that, 
```
for j in range(len(df)):
        ch='x'
        for paths, group in df[j].groupby(['Subject0','Activity0']):
            val=chr(ord(ch)+j)
            file_name = f"sensor-{val}.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a csv file (say data.csv) for each combination of 'S' and 'A' then you do groupby and then iterate over each group saving each group seperately

#### Sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [0,8,5,9,6],
    'Y': [1,5,6,8,7],
    'Z': [2,3,7,8,7],
    'S': [1,1,2,2,1],
    'A': [1,2,1,2,3]
})

for group_name, df_group in df.groupby(['S','A']):
  S = f"S{group_name[0]}"
  A = f"A{group_name[1]}"
  p = os.path.join(S, A)
  if not os.path.exists(p):
    os.makedirs(p)
    
  df_group[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(os.path.join(p, f"{S}_{A}.csv"), index=False)
```

You will get files in below directory structure:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, i am a bit new on this. lets say we have more than 3 colmns in a file how can I edit the part ```df_group[['X', 'Y', 'Z']]```

Comment: Just add the columns you want into the list. Say you want to save column 'C` also then you will have to do `df_group[['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'C']]`

Comment: i have 128 of them

Comment: you already have the group in each iteration, print(group_name) - see my answer.

Comment: if you want all then just use `df_group.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(...`